# cant get MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate

Tags: android

Am using ubuntu .am developing apps with google map.for that i registering for map apikey.I follwed the instruction in this following Link [link text](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)

from this instruction i got MD5 Fingerprint of Your Signing Certificate,also i have keystore ,But i cant able get MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate, for this I followed the commend 
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \
-keystore .keystore \
-storepass android -keypass android.

I specified the path_to_debug_keystore location according to my application location. But wen i execute that commend

I get the "bash: my-release-key.keystore: Permission denied."
I dont know which commend will i use to get this  MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate.can any one give me the solution for this.

Thanks in advance,
regards,
Lakshmanan.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cant get MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977428/cant-get-md5-fingerprint-of-the-sdk-debug-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

Find out where your debug.keystore is located -  where the avd manager is:

I realize you are using Linux, but 
in WindowsXP it's under "C:\Documents and Settings\[user]\.android\debug.keystore"

in Windows7:   C:\Users\[user]\.android\debug.keystore

I am not familiar with ubuntu - sorry.  But, the instructions should translate respectively.

So in the command prompt adapt this generic path reference to your specific info:
~path\keytool -list -keystore ~path.android\debug.keystore

Do not enter a password as there is none.

Look for the MD5 fingerprint