# cant get MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate

Tags: android

I am using Ubuntu.  I am developing apps with Google Maps.  For that I am registering for an apikey.  I followed the instruction in this following Link link text

from this instruction i got MD5 Fingerprint of Your Signing Certificate,also i have keystore ,But i cant able get MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate, for this I followed the commend keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \ -keystore .keystore \ -storepass android -keypass android.

I specified the path_to_debug_keystore location according to my application location. But wen i execute that commend

I get the "bash: my-release-key.keystore: Permission denied." I dont know which commend will i use to get this MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate.can any one give me the solution for this.

Thanks in advance, regards, Lakshmanan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get rid of the backslashes if you are typing this all on one line. Hence, it should look like:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

(assuming you are running this in the directory where your debug keystore resides, which is `~/.android` on Ubuntu)

Comment: I give this and i got fingerprint:keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <path-to default debug keystore> -storepass android -keypass android

Answer (score 5):

Use -v for jdk 1.7. Beginning with the Android SDK release v1.0, you need to apply for a free Google Maps API key before you can integrate Google Maps into your Android application. To apply for a key, you need to follow the series of steps outlined below. You can also refer to Google's detailed documentation on the process at http://code.google.com/Android/toolbox/apis/mapkey.html.

First, if you are testing the application on the Android emulator, locate the SDK debug certificate located in the default folder of "C: \Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Android". The filename of the debug keystore is debug.keystore. For deploying to a real Android device, substitute the debug.keystore file with your own keystore file. In a future article I will discuss how you can generate your own keystore file.

For simplicity, copy this file (debug.keystore) to a folder in C: \ (for example, create a folder called "C: \Android").

Using the debug keystore, you need to extract its MD5 fingerprint using the Keytool.exe application included with your JDK installation. This fingerprint is needed to apply for the free Google Maps key. You can usually find the Keytool.exe from the "C: \Program Files\Java\\bin" folder.

Issue the following command to extract the MD5 fingerprint.

C: \Program Files\Java\\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C: \Android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

Use -v for jdk 1.7

C: \Program Files\Java\\bin>keytool.exe -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C: \Android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

1. Open command prompt
2. Go to your jdk/bin directory
3. Type following

   `keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Akshay          Taru\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android`

**Note:** 1. Change "C:\Users\Akshay Taru.android\debug.keystore" to your .keystore

          2. Do not forget **double quotes** while specifying path.