# Why can't I get a my MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate?

Tags: keytool

I enter the following in the command prompt:

> keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \
>   -keystore keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \
>   -keystore C:\Users\kmmr12.android\debug.keystore \
>   -storepass android -keypass android \
>   -storepass android -keypass android

when I press enter I get:

> -keystore is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can find an answer, for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977428/cant-get-md5-fingerprint-of-the-sdk-debug-certificate).

As far as I can tell you're using the right tool but you're adding backslashes ( \ ) which might be causing your trouble.

Try writing the command without the backslashes (for instance

*keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey  -keystore keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey  -keystore C:\Users\kmmr12.android\debug.keystore  -storepass android -keypass android  -storepass android -keypass android*

)

Comment: Hi I tried this and I am still getting the error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well, I tried to run it against my own keyfile and was successful. However, a couple of questions about the way you're doing this: 1. Are you using Windows? 2. Where are you storing your keyfile? I ask this because I see you are writing "kmmr12.android" as  part of path and, if you're in Windows, it's likely that your actual path is c:\users\kmmr12\.android\

Comment: Hi I tried doing this in C:\Users\kmmr12\ and C:\Users\kmmr12\.android\ and C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02 I have also uploaded a keytool software on Eclipse. The path to the key store is C:\Users\kmmr12\.android\debug.keystore  I am not quite want you mean by keyfile

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I meant: look at the command you're writing. There's a backslash missing between kmmr12 and the .android directory

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I am using Windows 7 So according to what you are saying the key file should be in my .android folder or file?

Comment: so -keystore keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\kmmr12\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android - is the correct command?

Comment: and I should do from this directory? C:\Users\kmmr12\.android\

Comment: Not exactly. What I would do in your place is: 1. Move to the appropiate directory which contains the file  (cd c:\users\kmmr12\.android) 2. run the command (keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android -storepass android -keypass android)

Comment: Hi DigCamara, I just did you you instructed however I an still getting the same error. It really got me scratching my head here.

Comment: I got it using the keytool plug in much easier thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I believe you are using windows and that's why you get the message.

1. You should first go find your keytool (usually located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin)
2. Then add it to your windows path by going to System>Advanced System Settings>Environmental Variables. When you go there find the Path from the system variable lists, double click on it, add a ';' to the end of it and paste the location of your keytool folder.
3. Now you should be able to use the command keytool in windows!