# error for Display MapView into Android

Tags: android

this video showing the error for this Displaying map

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMzOB-OLtF0
![enter image description here][1]

now I'm generate Map API Key but it long ,now  I'm using windows Xp and when  you entered is said not valid ?

Key :C0:4E:4B:2C:F8:02:D9:CF:1C:DD:C2:1C:2D:0B:DC:8E:AB:8D:47:46

Comment: Please post the relevant code & configuration inline here, and describe your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapview is working fine.  What is not is the Map API key associated with the debug keystore used by the emulator.  You need to generate a map API key that is associated with that particular debug key.

Your release key will be different from the debug key.  You need a map API key for each.

Comment: I'm generate Map API Key and set it then display white map , such for in the  video , why ?

Comment: Make sure that the API key that is being used by the emulator matches the one you use to generate the API key exactly!  See the following for more details:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977016/cant-get-md5-fingerprint-of-the-sdk-debug-certificate/5863092#5863092

Comment: You want the MD5 fingerprint of the debug.keystore (wherever that is located).  That is what you will put to the API key generator.  You may want to generate a new debug key.  They are only good for 1 year, so you will have to do this every year.

Answer (score -1):

That is a sing of:

- no networking
- bad id used in map